# Exact diffuse initialization of the Kalman Filter: what does the design matrix look like?

Tags: statsmodels, kalman-filter

I am using Python (statsmodels) to create a dynamic factor model on which I apply the Kalman filter. Thanks to earlier questions on this forum, I landed upon using exact diffuse initialization. My code is below:

```
mod = DynamicFactor(
                    endog=NG.astype(float), # nobs x P
                    exog=HDD.astype(float), # nobs x k_exog
                    k_factors=1,
                    freq=NG.index.inferred_freq, # Which is daily data ('D') or start of the month ('MS')
                    factor_order=f,
                    error_order=0,
                    error_cov_type='diagonal'
)

mod.ssm.initialize_diffuse()
     
with mod.fix_params(dicts):
  
     res = mod.fit(
                   disp=True,
                   method='nm', #Nelder-Mead algorithm
                   xtol=10e-5,
                   maxiter=350000
                   )
```

Now I am interested in what the initial state equation would look like.
It should be of the form:
[image: Initial state equation]
And I know that Q0 is not just a very large number, because that would be approximate diffuse initialization.
In fact, I believe in the statsmodels package, the variance of the disturbance eta is set to 1/unity to avoid identification issues.

So this begs the question, what do the design matrix R (and Q0) look like in practice?